# Foolproof Strategy to Beat Civilization 2 on Any Level?

Tags: civilization-2

I'm curious to know if there is a foolproof way of beating Civ 2 everytime I play. I can do this on the first level and usually the second, but what about Deity level? Assume we're talking about conquest and not the space race.

Comment: Its worth clarifying, you are talking about Civilization2(1996) and not Civilization5(2010).

Comment: @Akusete - Yes, I'm talking about Civilization 2.

Comment: I, a "hardcore" player can USUALLY beat Civ II up to the King level. Sometimes at the Emperor level, for certain games that play like "king" (or if I'm lucky with resources etc.) Deity? Forget it, at least for me. Someone who knew all the game mechanics AND got lucky might beat Deity. Not me.(Except in some scenario games). Otherwise, the AI gets too far ahead.) It's all I can do to "get lucky" at the Emperor level.

Answer (score 5):

- Expand, expand, expand. Upside to this you get a lot of cities and can make a lot of units to keep attacking/guarding. Downside is your economy isn't the greatest, and you have to rely on continuing to attack/pressure the enemy into giving you money/resources.

OR

- Turtle till you got large army and slowly expand taking over cities slowly, the downside to this is that you stay at war for forever which sucks. If you go this route try to only be at war with 1 race at a time, even if you have to pay tribute to someone. And make sure to destroy them completely, take over any good cities, and destroy the others as it hurts your economy and a weak city is just saying attack me please.

I am referring mainly to Civ 2 here, but this works in Civ 4 mostly as well. I haven't gotten 5 yet so unsure of that.

EDIT:
Oh in Civ 2 my very favorite unit was stealth bombers once you got them, just bomb the hell out of the enemy, there is nothing they can do when you send 50+ bombers at one city, then wait 1 turn to repair and go against another city. It got to the point I always had half my bombers repairing (i.e waiting a couple of turns) and the rest attacking.

Once you get normal bombers things are all uphill from there.

Comment: Interesting answer: these two different approaches remind me of what real-world empires (such as the Roman Empire) did, and the problems they had

Comment: I'm used to the turtle strategy, but on higher dificulties the computer grows so fast that I get overrun easily. I'm trying the expand-fast strategy now.

Comment: The only problem with bombers is that it requires flight, which cancels your Colossus. If you were playing with a MSC, your science output probably drops by about 20-25% without the trade bonus from Colossus.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who easily managed Civ2 on Deity level (unlike Civ3 and Civ4, where the AI already beat me up on King) I would like to add a little aspect that I remeber from the good old days in addition to [Vipers answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10577/foolproof-strategy-to-beat-civilization-2-on-any-level/10604#10604) : The Artillery unit in Civ2 is incredibly powerful. I remember stomping over several enemy cities in one round with one artillery (railroads available).

Comment: Yep very true .